# Django - StringRelatedField() not applied to query results when .values() provided

Tags: django, django-views, django-serializer

In my Django app, I'm finding that a `StringRelatedField()` on a serializer class isn't being applied when that serializer is used on a filter query where a set of field values have been specified - though it does work if the query returns all fields. Whew, that's a mouthful, let me break it down -

I have two models, `Report` and `User`; each `Report` is associated with a `User`. Ideally, I want to query reports via `get_queryset` and in each report record, the value of the associated `user` should be the result of `StringRelatedField()`, the return value of the `__str__` method on the `User` model (which is the user's first and last names).

If my query returns all fields, this works perfectly... so the query

```
Report.objects.filter(location__within=some_other_model.region)
```

does the trick.

However, I've found that querying only for the `values` that I actually need vastly improves performance, so my preference is to query like so:

```
Report.objects.filter(location__within=some_other_model.region).values('id',
                                                                       'location',
                                                                       'user',)
```

but the results of that query have the UUID foreign key of the record from the `User` table, they do not seem to have been replaced with the `StringRelatedField()`.

Below, I have the view and serializer for `Report`, as well as the `User` model.

```
# report/view.py

class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReportReadSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
            some_other_model = get_object_or_404(Organization, pk='some_other_model_id')

            # remove the .values() and this works correctly
            return Report.objects.filter(location__within=some_other_model.region).values('id',
                                                                                           'location',
                                                                                           'user',)
```

```
# report/serializers.py

class ReportReadSerializer(serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.GeometryField(precision=4)
    user = StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Observation
        geo_field = 'location'
        fields = [
            'id',
            'location',
            'user',
        ]
```

```
# user/models.py

class User(SoftDeletionModel):
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior for `StringRelatedField()`

The `StringRelatedField` returns ***the `str` representation of the value*** and in your case, the user is having an ***integer*** value. If you were using the `QuerySet` (without calling the `values()`), the user will have a `User` instance and thus the `str` representation will give you the proper result.

You had felt a performance improvement because the `values('id', 'location', 'user', )` fetching the values from a single table (note that, calling `user` will not make an inner join here) and there is no chance for an `N+1` problem. But, if you were using the User's `str` method, Django will make an inner join and there will be an `N+1` problem and thus you will have performance issues.

So, you have two options,

1. Use values and ignore the `User`'s representation
2. Use [**`select_related()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReportReadSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        some_other_model = get_object_or_404(Organization, pk='some_other_model_id')
        return Report.objects.filter(
            location__within=some_other_model.region
        ).select_related("user")
```

Comment: That is a terrific explanation, thank you so much for helping me to understand this. `select_related()` seems to be the best solution for me - from the docs: `"Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries."`